# how to format int number output with thousand separator in hive sql

Tags: hive

Do you know how to format the output of a number in hive with thousand separator? For example:

data:146452664

output:146,452,664

I use this in Teradata, but don't know how to achieve in Hive.

```
cast(cast(cast(number as integer) as format'ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9') as char(11))
```

Comment: There's `format_number()` but Hive also supports `printf()` function for arbitrary formatting... RTFM! https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Comment: Thanks very much! format_number() functions works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `format_number()` function.

```
select format_number(146452664,0)
```

The first argument is the number and second is the number of decimal places to round.If D is 0, the result has no decimal point.

Comment: This function will change the type from number to string, and I need to sort finally, any method we can format the output without transforming to string?

Comment: @Sharon Jin : why not sort first and then do the format?

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak , absolutely! I finally did that way, thanks!